# How to wrap c++ std::shared_ptr in wrapper headerfile so it can be called from c?

Tags: c++, c

I'm writing a small Wrapper API so i can call some `C++` code (classes/ functions) from `C`.
I got the problem, that one of my `C++` functions is initialised in my wrapper header with a `"shared_ptr"`.

```
ClassName *ClassName _new(std::shared_ptr<Lib::Instance> p_Instance);
```

So as you can see, the wrapper file is infested with C++ style. This is bad because the Wrapper file `should be readable by C AND C++`.

This is my Wrapper.h file:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif /* __cplusplus */

typedef struct ClassName ClassName;

ClassName *ClassName_new(std::shared_ptr<Lib::Instance> p_Instance);

void ClassName_setValue(ClassName* t, double p_value);

void ClassName_delete(ClassName* t);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif /* __cplusplus */
```

and this is my Wrapper.cpp file:

```
#include "Wrapper.h"
#include "ClassName.h"

extern "C"{

ClassName* ClassName_new(std::shared_ptr<Lib::Instance> p_Instance){
       return new ClassName(p_Instance);
}

void ClassName_setValue(ClassName* t, double p_value){
        t->setValue(p_value);
}

void ClassName_delete(ClassName* t){
        delete t;
}
}
```

And this is the part of my main .cpp file
Header:

```
class ClassName: public Lib::Util::Task {
public:
   ClassName(std::shared_ptr<Lib::Instance> p_Instance);
   virtual ~ClassName();
   void setValue(double p_value);
   ...
```

.Cpp:

```
ClassName::ClassName(std::shared_ptr<Lib::Instance> p_Instance) ...
...
   void ClassName::setValue(double p_value){
      doSomething()
   }
...
```

I'm not allowed to change my structure of the main c++ file where I am using the `ClassName(std::shared_ptr<Lib::Instance> p_Instance);`

Do you have any ideas how I can fix this problem? 
Maybe writing a second Wrapper?

Edit:
Here is the error  given by the Terminal:

```
Wrapper.h:21:45: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘:’ token
 ClassName *ClassName_new(std::shared_ptr<Lib::Instance> p_Instance);
                             ^
```

Comment: `Lib::Instance` isn't a valid name in C. This is a non-starter.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. I just changed all my names, these arent the real ones :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function cannot be used in C, so you can use the pre-processor to remove the declaration just like you used with `extern "C"`:

```
// Wrapper.h
#ifdef __cplusplus
ClassName *ClassName_new(std::shared_ptr<Lib::Instance> p_Instance);
#endif
```

Although, it this wrapper isn't supposed to be used in C++ by anything other than Wrapper.cpp, then moving the declaration into Wrapper.cpp might be a better option.

---

If you need a way of invoking `ClassName_new` from C, I would suggest steering away from shared pointer. But you *could* make it work with an opaque wrapper:

```
// Wrapper.h
struct opaque_wrapper* make_instance(void);
void release_instance(struct opaque_wrapper*);
ClassName *ClassName_new(struct opaque_wrapper*);

// Wrapper.cpp
struct opaque_wrapper {
    std::shared_ptr<Lib::Instance> p_Instance;
};
opaque_wrapper* make_instance() {
    return new opaque_wrapper{std::make_shared<Lib::Instance>()};
}
void release_instance(struct opaque_wrapper* instance) {
    delete instance;
}
ClassName *ClassName_new(struct opaque_wrapper* instance) {
    return ClassName_new(instance->p_Instance);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this wont work out in my .cpp wrapper file, because the error is coming from the header wrapper file.. ;)

Comment: @KaiSchoening See the edited version. I copied the wrong declaration initially.

Comment: Thank you! this worked out, but for now i'm getting an Memory access error.. :D

Comment: Anyways, doesn't that mean that this wrapped wrapper header part isn't read by c? how does "c" know then that there is ClassName *ClassName_new(std::shared_ptr<Lib::Instance> p_Instance)?

Comment: @KaiSchoening It doesn't know about it, which is good because it musn't know about it since it cannot understand it.

Comment: Hey guys, I tried o figure out why i got an Memory access error. I used gdb to see which line it causes. It says: return new `ClassName(p_Instance);` causes the error. This appeared after i added: `#ifdef __cplusplus
ClassName *ClassName_new(std::shared_ptr<Lib::Instance> p_Instance);
#endif`

Comment: This is what i got as error: Cannot access memory at address 0x1>) at Wrapper.cpp

Comment: I tried the opaque way, but I'm not very clear about how to implement this in c... maybe you can help? I'm getting the following error: `error: expected expression before ‘struct’
  struct ClassName* c = ClassName_new(struct opaque_wrapper* instance);`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest embedding the reference counter into the object and use `boost::intrusive_ptr` with it. This way you can pass a plain pointer to C functions and those C functions can still manage the object's lifetime directly calling C-style `addref/release` on it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use classes from C++ in C.

You can define function prototypes of C calling convention C functions, to be used from C++ with the following wrapper code around in the header file:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/* put here C calling convention C functions */

#ifdef __cplusplus
};
#endif
```

and you'll get a definitions file that can be used either in C or in C++.  `__cplusplus` is a macro defined by the c++ compiler when compiling C++ code, and it introduces the `extern "C" {` environment to support C functions.  Those functions follow the C style calling conventions (you cannot overload them, you cannot use method definitions or define classes in there)