# How to call opaque_wrapper struct from c?

Tags: c, struct, wrapper

This questions refers to my older question: [How to wrap c++ std::shared_ptr in wrapper headerfile so it can be called from c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58080505/how-to-wrap-c-stdshared-ptr-in-wrapper-headerfile-so-it-can-be-called-from-c)

So please read that one first so you can understand at what position I'm right now.

I'm wondering how I can call my struct:
`ClassName* c = newClassName(struct opaque_wrapper* instance);` in c, without getting this error:
`error: expected expression before ‘struct’
  struct ClassName* c = ClassName_new(struct opaque_wrapper* instance);`

So here is my Wrapper.h file:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif /* __cplusplus */

struct opaque_wrapper* make_instance(void);
void release_instance(struct opaque_wrapper*);

typedef struct ClassName ClassName;

ClassName* newClassName(struct opaque_wrapper*);

void ClassName_setValue(ClassName* v, double p_value);

void deleteClassName(ClassName* v);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif /* __cplusplus */
```

I just want to have this struct, so i don't have to implement `std::shared_ptr<Lib::Instance> p_Instance` in my Wrapper.h file.

I hope that this will help me to implement the `ClassName_setValue(...)`; in my main() in c!

Comment: You talk about an error in your C implementation, yet post the C++ implementation. Please include the code that actually produces the error and add the full error message including the line where it happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call syntax is wrong and should be something like:

```
opaque_wrapper* intance = make_instance();

ClassName* c = newClassName(intance);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your call syntax is invalid. I urge you to work through an introduction to C before progressing.

In a nutshell, your call is mixing up the syntax for declaring and calling a function (and the error message you posted belongs to a different piece of code, not the one you’ve posted!).

To fix the call to `newClassName`, you first need to have defined an initialised an object of type `struct opaque_wrapper` which, by the way, isn’t declared anywhere in your header (you need to add its declaration).

Assuming you have an initialised pointer `pwrapper` of type `struct opaque_wrapper *`, you can then call the function as follows:

```c
ClassName *c = newClassName(pwrapper);
```